# How to add Javascript inside a <script> tag in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently trying to add this code to a PHP file:

```
if (contains($current_url, $bad_urls_2)) {
    echo '<script>
           $('body :not(script,sup)').contents().filter(function() {
               return this.nodeType === 3;}).replaceWith(function() {
               return this.nodeValue.replace(/[®]/g, '<sup>$&</sup>');
           });</script>';
}
```

the issue with this is that it outputs this error: 
`Error: syntax error, unexpected 'body' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';': syntax error, unexpected 'body' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'` 
 The `if` statement is not necessary for this issue, as it only checks if there is a word in an URLs and then applies this code only to the pages that match them.

Comment: You have `'` (single quote) before `body` which closes the sting you started on the previous line

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for saying this, this acutally also broke the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use heredoc https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
<?php

if (contains($current_url, $bad_urls_2)) {
    echo <<<JS
<script>
$('body :not(script,sup)').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3;}).replaceWith(function() {
   return this.nodeValue.replace(/[®]/g, '<sup>$&</sup>\);
});
</script>
JS;
}
```